# Is there a function like SendKeys (form based .NET) in ASP.NET (Web based)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sendkeys

I'd like to find a way to automatically send the copy command keystrokes (Ctrl C) upon loading a web based form in ASP.NET. I know the form based .NET has a SendKeys class but I've yet to find anything similar with ASP.net. Does anyone know of a possible solution to sending automatic keystrokes in ASP.NET?

Comment: Can you explain more what problem you are trying to solve?  There is no guarantee what Ctrl C does in any particular browser. My iPhone and iPad don't even have a Ctrl key.  Not sure what sending a control sequence would do, even if you could do it.  BTW, I hope the answer is "this is impossible".  Not not an expert on JavaScript though

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to programatically execute copy and paste tasks from a web application, as this would pose an obvious security risk.  However, if you are looking to make it easier for users to copy data from the web application to their clipboard, you can use something like [ZeroClipboard](http://zeroclipboard.org/), which uses Flash to implement the copy functionality.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even consider the security aspect. Thanks, I'll look into that and see if it can help solve my problem.